# how to scroll the collectionview and pass the data selected from the tableview which is inside of the collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

i have collectionview.In the collectionviewcell my code as below:-

class Headercell: UICollectionViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,RadioDummyTableViewCellDelegate{

```
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    let cellIdentifier: String = "tableCell"

    var optionsModelArray:[OptionsModel] = []

    var options:[String]? = []

    var questionviewmodel:DummyDataModel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


        // tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self


      //  tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
      tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DummyDataHeader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

   }


    func setReviewData(reviews:DummyDataModel)

    {
        self.lblName.text = reviews.question
        print(self.lblName.text)

        print(reviews.options)


        for values in reviews.options!{

            print(values)

            let optionmodel = OptionsModel(values: values)
            self.optionsModelArray.append(optionmodel)
        }
    }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.optionsModelArray.count

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 44

    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> NH_OptionsModel{


        return self.optionsModelArray[indexPath.row]

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DummyDataHeader

        cell.setOptions(Options1:datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        cell.delegate1 = self



        return cell

    }
```

so in the collectionviewcell i have  tableview.

In the tableviewcell :-

```
//use of protocol in button action
protocol NHRadioDummyTableViewCellDelegate : class {
    //function
    func swiftyTableViewCellDidTapRadio(_ sender: DummyDataHeader)
}



class DummyDataHeader: UITableViewCell {


    var delegate1:RadioDummyTableViewCellDelegate?
  func setReviewData(reviews:OptionsModel)

    {
        self.optionLabel?.text = reviews.values
        print(self.optionLabel?.text)
    }


}
```

The problem is.

When i select the tableviewcell i need to scroll the collectionviewcell and also the data of the tableview.

Comment: Can you properly explain your last line to assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

add the delegate in the collectionview cell instead of tableview cell. Implement tableview didselectrow at index method in collectionview cell and call the delegate function in it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    guard let cell = tableView.cellforRowAt(indexPath) as? DummyDataHeader else { return }
    delegate?.swiftyTableViewCellDidTapRadio(cell)
}
```